# Z-Indexing Not working

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where I can't seem to get my z-indexing to work on the .dropdown div in my menu. Does anybody have an idea as to why this isn't working?

My CSS states that it should be at a level of 5 which is higher than any other on the page:

```
ul.dimensions > li.open > ul.dropdown {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 261px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: 1px solid #afafaf;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-top: -1px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yn979r0g/

Comment: "level of 5 which is higher than any other on the page:" This isn't true at all because you have `z-index: 10` in your CSS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul.dimensions>li.open{
    z-index:6;
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/yn979r0g/2/

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that any element with a z-index creates a new "structure" underneath it. The li each have a z-index of 4, so they are all at the same height and then ordered by their position on the page. The z-index of 5 that you give to a descendant of that li only makes it high RELATIVE to other children of the li.

One option is to change the z-index of the parent li when it is opened, using a class and some javascript.

EDIT: looks like someone beat me to it with posting the code, so I'll just leave this as an explanation for why it works that way.

Comment: I believe the "structure" to which you're referring in this case is called a "stacking context": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Yes, thanks! I couldn't remember the official term, which is why I left it in quotes.