# HTML - Popover ist not overlapping with z-index

Tags: z-index

z-index is not working

i tried: 
[Z-Index not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016927/z-index-not-working)

[Z-index not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493722/z-index-not-working)

[Z-Indexing Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844365/z-indexing-not-working)

```
#customers-list {
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: -160px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

The Popover still overlaps the most, but not all elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the soulution:
z-index has to be applied to the `positioned` elements, in my case: to that elements that having `position: absolute;`

see mozilla [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) and [stacking-context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#customers-list {
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: -160px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000!important;
}
```